# Angular grid with expandable rows

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I'm looking for angular grid that support several features:

- Data via Ajax
- Sort and pagination
- Sticky headers
- Expandable rows, mean clicking on a row will open a new row beneath it with additional data about the row - templated by me

If you know of which, please tell.

p.s.
`ng-grid` support all excepts the expandable rows.

Answer (score 1):

This [Angular Grid](http://www.angulargrid.com) can do it (assuming I understand what you mean by sticky headers). One of the things you can do is give the grid a tree structure of data and then the user can expand the rows to get to deeper levels. The example [here](http://www.angulargrid.com/example-file-browser/index.php) shows passing such a structure to the grid.

Comment: can any1 also share the same for Angular2 Typescript ?

Answer (score 0):

ng-grid has been updated by the Angular team, and is now called [UI-grid](http://ui-grid.info/).  It now supports all of your requirements, including expandable rows.